# Does WMI data exist only when a program fetches it?

Tags: windows, wmi, wmi-query

Let's say I fetch data from `select * from Win32_TemperatureProbe` - is that location populated with the sensor data whether I query it or not, or rather, is it loaded on demand, that is when I query it, the WMI engine in turn interrogates the hardware itself and only then reports the data back - In essence, does the query create overhead beyond simply going to the WMI data store or is it written to anyways?

Answer (score 1):

WMI itself is a Windows service and the data depends on the provider. In the case of Win32_TemperatureProbe, the data is dynamically provided:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/cimwin32-wmi-providers